# SED find and replace - MapReduce file

Tags: mysql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Im trying to find and replace all "^A" characters with a "\t" so that I can import the data into a mysql database. The command Im using on OSX is:

```
sed -i '' 's/^A/\t/' item_info_20130203 > item_info_20130203_tab
```

This just deletes all the contents in the file. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command should actually be something like this:

```
sed 's/'`echo "\001"`'/\t/g' item_info_20130203 > item_info_20130203_tab
```

or the more modern way

```
sed 's/'$(echo "\001")'/\t/g' item_info_20130203 > item_info_20130203_tab
```

or to affect the original file:

```
sed -i 's/'`echo "\001"`'/\t/g' item_info_20130203
```

If you are using GNU sed, you can use this:

```
sed -i 's/\x01/\t/g' item_info_20130203
```

Comment: It did not worked here. I needed to add the -e arg to echo. So the command would be: sed 's/'$(echo -e "\001")'/\t/g' item_info_20130203

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/161979-sed-i-option-example.html), sed's -i option finds/replaces text in the original file, so the syntax `> item_info_20120203_tab` at the end of your command is a NOP and hence the output file is empty.

Comment: After removing the output file, and rerunning, the original file is still the same.

Comment: The single character space after the '-i' argument should not be there either. And I believe you'll have to represent the ^A as hex if you'd like to find/replace that byte (and not run the find/replace on the regular expression ^A).